# Make Django admin use translated field names

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, admin

I'm doing a localization of a Django app.

The front-end website works fine and the Django admin site picks up the selected language as well.

But it only applies the language settings in some places and uses the default English versions of field and column names, even though these have been translated. Why? **How can I make it use the translated names for column and field names in the admin interface?**

Example:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    OPTIONS = ( (0, _("Bank transfer") ), (1, _("Cash on delivery") ), )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, name=_("User") )
    payment = models.IntegerField(choices=self.OPTIONS, name=_("Payment"))
```

For which I get:

1. Translated standard admin texts such as "Welcome" and "Logout" at the top
2. Translated SELECT options for the payment type
3. NOT translated column names and form labels for the fields ("User", "Payment")

I'm using Django 1.0.2. The texts that are not getting translated did appear in the locale files along with those that work.

Sub-question: is it possible to localize the app names?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turned out I was setting a translated version for **name** instead of **verbose_name**.

This works:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    OPTIONS = ( (0, _("Bank transfer") ), (1, _("Cash on delivery") ), )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("User") )
    payment = models.IntegerField(choices=self.OPTIONS, verbose_name=_("Payment"))
```

Comment: Where did the `self` name in `self.OPTIONS` come from? Doesn't this raise a NameError?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling I'm not very good at Python but doesn't self refer to the module itself in this case? OPTIONS is defined right above "class Order"...

Comment: The first parameter of a bound method is the object itself. By convention this is named self, but `self` is no magic keyword like `this` is in JavaScript or PHP; it has to be explicitly bound. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

TomA got the right answer.

But Django now takes the first argument as the verbose name of a field, [except](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) for the `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField` and `OneToOneField` field types.
So if you are lazy you can also write:

```
payment = models.IntegerField(_("Payment"), choices=self.OPTIONS)
```

You still have to use a keyword argument for the `ForeignKey` example, though:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("User"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps using a custom ModelForm for this model (in admin.py)? You'll need to add a gettext-ed value for the label of the fields you override.

Localizing app names is not possible, as of Django 1.0 - not sure of 1.1.